# An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not supported

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, insert, submitchanges

My project is divided to PresentationLayer, BusinesLogicLayer and DataAccessLayer. Every created object goes through these layers. 
In simplifying:

SetFilter.xaml.cs

```
FilterFactory fFactory = new FilterFactory();
Filter myFilter = fFactory.Create(someClient, time, message);
FilterBLO filterBLO = new FilterBLO();
filterBLO.Save(myFilter);
```

FilterBLO.cs

```
FilterDAO filterDAO = new FilterDAO();
using (TransactionScope transcope = new TransactionScope())
{
    filterDAO.Save(myFilter);
    transcope.Complete()
}
```

FilterDAO.cs

```
using(DBDataContext dbdc = new DBDataContext)
{
    dbdc.Filter.InsertOnSubmit(myFilter);
    changeSet = dbdc.GetChangeSet();
    dbdc.SubmitChanges()
}
```

Filter is connected with table `Client` using `ClientFilter` table containing `FilterID` and `ClientID`. (many-to-many relationship)

If I create new 3 objects everything's ok, but if I'm getting existing `Client` in database (also using `ClientBLO` and `ClientDAO` so in separate `TransactionScope` and separate `DBDataContext`) I get error:

> An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new,
>   perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not
>   supported.

(I searched other similar threads but I didn't found solution to my problem.)

And finally my question

How should I save `myFilter` if `Client` exists in database. I tried `Attach()` it to datacontext in `FilterDAO.cs` but I get the same error.

Comment: Where/how does `myFilter` get created?

Comment: @ChrisF I added this section. In xaml.cs (presentationLayer) using FilterFactory()

Comment: What does `FilterFactory` do?

Comment: @ChrisF Just return new Filter(someClient, time, message);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to obtain Client from the database with the same DataContext you use to InsertOnSubmit the Filter; then you have to set Client value in the Filter object with that object before InsertOnSubmit.

Comment: I know that's because of another DataContext, but I don't have a good idea how to make it in my structure. And maybe there's some other solution than global DataContext (because I think such a division is better solution, isn't it?)

Comment: It should in non transactional scenario.
How about passing the DataContext to the DAL and crating a new one if the one passed is null?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you propose, return DataContext from ClientDAL to PresentationLayer and pass it again to FilterDAL? It is kinf of solution, but I'm not sure how to the correctness such an action from the perspective of sql and linq

Comment: I think you'd better to rely on obtaining the DataContextfrom a factory; get it in the PresentationLayer (where the transactional logic begins and ends) and pass it to all your xxDAO classes. All xxxDAO classes should then accept a DataContext argument and if null call the same factory you use in the presentation layer.